# Manage Azure Active Directory application manifest through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-activedirectory

I have a large number of applications running in Azure that need to have some very specific values set in their Manifests in the Active Directory section of the old Azure Management portal. Is there a cmdlet or other way to retrieve and set manifests for such applications through PowerShell ?

Answer (score 0):

The manifest is not a physical file, but a way for the 'system' to set values using the Graph API.
You can set these values yourself using your tenants graph api endpoint, see
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference
for further referencen to the api object

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.